# What's a better way of updating to a remote branch than deleting it locally and recreating it? (Git)

Tags: git

I'm working at a company where I need to run code on test machines. I usually write code on my dev machine and push it. Then, I pull it from the test machine.

Sometimes, I make temporary changes on my test machine and I want to reset it to be exactly the same as the remote branch. I have to delete the branch locally and then re-create the branch locally. This is pretty tedious, is there a better way?

I tried this but I somehow got merge conflicts:

```
git reset --hard
git pull
```